repeat bash command until output does not contain a given string
I often need to run different commands that would need to be re-run immediately after if the output contains a given string (status code is not enough).
Ideally the way to repeat it could be piped so I can easily use the logic to different commands.
e.g.
my_command -a | repeat_until_words

One approach I have in mind is to somehow store the output in a variable/file and do a search inside it, but I wonder if there is a better approach.

You could try something with a bash while loop:
while my_command -a | grep 'foobar'; do true; done

Add the -q option of grep to suppress its output. To do the opposite and stop when the output contains a given string:
while my_command -a | grep -v 'barfoo'; do true; done


Had fun with your solution: while date | grep -v "13:16"; do sleep 1; true; done ...
Mie 31 Iul 2024 13:15:57 EEST Mie 31 Iul 2024 13:15:58 EEST Mie 31 Iul 2024 13:15:59 EEST
... and stopped gracefully.

Yep, funny. Note that in this case true is not even needed.

note that lines of my_command output that don't match foobar will not be displayed in the first case, and lines that match barfoo will not be displayed in the second case

actually, there's also a bug: you need equivalent of  !grep rather than grep -v. Consider: cat /dev/null | grep -v barfoo && echo notfound

I would write a bash function to achieve this, something like:
repeat_until_match() {
    local command="$1"
    local string="$2"
    
    while true; do
        output=$($command)
        
        if [[ "$output" == *"$string"* ]]; then
            break
        fi
        
        sleep 1
    done
}

Then you can run it like this:
repeat_until_match "command you want to run" "words you want to match"


This is likely to run into the problem described in BashFAQ/050 if command is anything more than a simple command with trivially splittable arguments.

repeat_until(){
    local cmp=() v=0 modes=(run stop) mode=-F
    while true; do
        case $1 in
            -[EFP]) mode=$1; shift ;;
            -v) ((v=!v)); shift ;;
            -x) cmp=$2; shift 2 ;;
            --) shift; break ;;
            -*) return 1 ;;
             *) break ;;
        esac
    done
    if [[ -z $cmp ]]; then
        [[ $1 ]] || return 2
        cmp=(grep -q $mode -- "$1")
        shift
    fi
    [[ $1 ]] || return 3
    local state=$(mktemp -d)
    mkfifo "$state"/fifo
    while
        "$@" > >(tee >(
            {
                "${cmp[@]}" >/dev/null &&
                echo ${modes[!v]} ||
                echo ${modes[v]}
            } >"$state"/fifo
        ))
        # true # uncomment to ignore exit status of cmd
    do
        read mode <"$state"/fifo
        [[ $mode = run ]] || break
    done
    rm -r "$state"
}

repeat_while(){ repeat_until -v "$@"; }

Usage:
repeat_until [-v] [-F] [--] string cmd [arg...]
repeat_until [-v] -E|-P [--] regex cmd [arg...]
repeat_until [-v] -x cmp [--] cmd [arg...]


-- terminates option processing
repeat_while is repeat_until -v
-v inverts test (until becomes while / while becomes until)
cmd and cmp can be programs or shell functions
cmp should return zero on success or non-zero on failure
-F / -E / -P set grep operating mode

Examples:
# loop until time reaches 15 seconds past
repeat_until ':15 ' date

# loop until seconds are even
repeat_until -E ':.[24680] ' date

# loop while minute is start-time minute
repeat_while $(date +:%M:) date

# loop printing and incrementing n until n is a multiple of 13
print+inc(){ echo $n; ((n++)); }
mod13(){ [[ $((n%13)) = 0 ]]; }
n=123; repeat_while -v -x mod13 print+inc


to be thorough, need to check that mktemp and mkfifo succeed. probably more
